# What is $\mathbf{S}$ (sample covariance matrix) in image compression based on PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, dimensionality-reduction

If the feature vector is $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$,
then to apply PCA we first need to construct the "sample covariance matrix)
\begin{align*}
\underbrace{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(\mathbf{x}^i-\bar{\mathbf{x}})(\mathbf{x}^i-\bar{\mathbf{x}})^T\bigg]}_{\text{$\mathbf{S}$ : sample covariance matrix}}
\end{align*}
from $N$ data points.

When I read a machine learning book, I encountered with the following:

[image]

What is $\mathbf{S}$ (sample covariance matrix) here in image compression based on PCA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! There's actually some ambiguity here: it's possible to consider the lower-dimensional projection with respect to the pixels within a single image *or* across a dataset of images.

#### A dataset of images

You're probably thinking of the case where you find principal components with respect to a dataset of images. A common example is "[eigenfaces](https://machinelearningmastery.com/face-recognition-using-principal-component-analysis/)".

Each sample corresponds to an image. $\mathbf{x}^i$ corresponds to (the grayscale pixel values) of a single image, and $\bar{\mathbf{x}}$ corresponds to the average (grayscale pixel values) of a single image. Here, $S$ corresponds to the variance between pixels across a dataset of images.

#### A single image

PCA greedily finds directions in feature space that have the greatest variance across samples. So if you have a single image, you need to split that image into equally shaped chunks. Each chunk in the image is a sample and each pixel within that chunk is a feature.

For example, if you have a 128x128 image, you might choose each row to be a sample. You'd then have 128 samples of chunks, each with 128 features. $S$ then describes the covariance across the rows of the image. You can find an implementation of what I described in [this tutorial](https://www.dataknowsall.com/imagepca.html).

Comment: What do you mean by "$\tilde{\mathbf{x}}$ corresponds to the average (grayscale pixel values) of a single image." Do you mean the reconstructed image $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$? If so, why average?

Comment: @DSPinfinity oh sorry I meant x^bar